# in c++, can a return statement be inside a catch block that is inside a for loop?

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is write code that breaks out of a for loop if an exception is thrown. Can this be achieved by simply using return in the catch block? or do I have to use break somehow?

for example, 1. will this function return 0 or 1?
2. will the first return statement break the for loop or
3. will it keep on looping?

Thank you in advance!!

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            if (i = 0) {
                throw fake_error;
            }
        } 
        catch(fake_error) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return i;
}
```

Comment: This function won't compile (and so won't run, and so won't return anything). In the second `return i;` statement, `i` is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: You can't separate a `try` from a `catch` like this. The `catch` has to be immediately following the `try`. You could put the entire `for` loop inside the `try` block and `catch` stuff that results from it, perhaps.

Comment: You may want to fix your indentation. It's really hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Unrelated, but `if (i = 0)` is a really common mistake. You probably wanted to do: `if (i == 0)`

Comment: @NathanPierson In the code shown, `catch` does follow `try`. The indentation is misleading.

Comment: It's also unclear what `fake_error` is. If it names an object, then `catch(fake_error)` is ill-formed. If it names a type, then `throw fake_error;` is ill-formed.

Comment: In any case, I don't see the point of `try`/`catch` here. Why not simply `if (i = 0) { return i; }` ?

Comment: There is so much wrong with this snippet. Your in a CS class, I am too, FYI. First I believe you can probably just do `if(i) throw fake_error`, what is a fake error, I havn't heard of them if they are a thing? Also you cant say `if(i = 0)` because that is an assignment of I, its like saying, make i zero. It should be `if(i == 0) do foo;`. You also cannot return `i` outside of the `for loop`, once you leave the loop, i is no longer in your local scope.  Also, `i` will be zero everytime, because you set i to zero in the declaration of the loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik because `if(i=0) {return i;}` will throw a compilation error.

Comment: to break out of a loop just use the `break` statement.

Comment: Your function is in main, so if you return anything, you will end your entire process, in other words; you will break from the entire program.

Comment: ...Though one of my professors says not to use `break` so IDK, but I do know using break is better than what you got now.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I would guess that the point of try-catch here is that throwing the exception could have been thrown into a separate function that `main()` would call. However, this would be more complex than the simplification in the question's current code. It's not real code, but a minimal example that reproduces the scenario in question (or it would if it were not for all the errors). *Admittedly, the code could have been made even simpler by leaving out that bugged `if`; just `try { throw fake_error; } catch // etc.` should have been enough unless I'm missing something.*

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/vWGMvKs5T)

Answer (score 1):

Any block can try catch, though while allowed I recommend to use a bigger scope. (exceptions are the biggest exception to the "don't pay for what you don't use" rule in c++).

To avoid having to put your exception into the inner loop you can create your own exception and put the information you want to have available in the catch block inside the exception. So this example shows you how to do that, also catch exceptions by const& this will avoid unecessary copying and/or modification of the exception content.

```
#include <stdexcept>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// declare/define an exception that can hold an int.

class my_exception :
    std::exception
{
public: 
    // always declare constructors with one parameter explicit
    // or they can be used in implicit type-conversions
    explicit my_exception(const int value) :
        m_value{ value }
    {
    }

    // accessor to data        
    const int& value() const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() 
{
    int retval{ 0 };

    // with our own exception we can
    // move the try-catch block out of the loop.
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            if (i == 1) throw my_exception(i);
        }
    }
    catch(const my_exception& e)
    {
        retval = e.value();
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the entire for loop is a much better way to go about it.

Comment: Yes I considered moving the whole loop to a seperate function. But I didn't want to show too much at one time.

Comment: Of course `if (i == 1) { retval = i; break; }` would have been much more straightforward.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sure! The rule still is don't use exceptions for the expected. But the question was about exception handling. So there it is :) (You probably would love this : herb sutter on optimizing rtti/exceptions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARYP83yNAWk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

C++ allows try/catch inside any block of statements, including a `for()` loop block.

However, you may want to consider doing it otherwise if possible just because it is *slow* (if the for() is only expected to go over a small number of iterations, then not big deal).